# Ubuntu 14.04 windows 7 dual boot problem

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Initially, I have installed windows 7 Ultimate on my lenovo laptop.

Later, I did install Ubuntu 14.04.

It shows the dual boot option when booting.

But if I select the Windows loader option then it just shows a red screen with some white dots on it and then it remains this way. Whereas if Ubuntu is selected, then Ubuntu loads fine.

How to make Windows to load as usual?

Answer (score 0):

This is a nightmare, I have a lenovo y510p. This UEFI boot is very problematic. Each time that that I have to update the ubuntu boot loader I have manually fix the boot. Another problem is the recovery partition. This partition also have a bootloader. In my case is the only one that ubuntu finds. Finally, there is something hardcode on the lenovo boot system to make the recover button works. In the end, I bought a second HD and I use the bios boot manager to choose which HD I want to boot. In my case is the key F12 on the beginning of the boot.

[this link show how to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported?lq=1)